# Using exponents and absolute values with 18 points of accuracy c#

Tags: c#, double, long-integer

I am trying to write a program that will allow me to do the following calculation with at least 18 digits of accuracy.

```
retMin = (long)((Math.Abs(ret)+Math.Abs(retMin))*Math.Pow(-1,Math.Abs(i)));
```

I believe this code would work if not for the use of the Math class which takes out puts doubles.

Is there a way to do this without using doubles?

Comment: Why not just replace `Math.Pow(-1,Math.Abs(i))` with `i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1`?

Comment: wow that seem so obvious now I can't believe I didn't think of it

Answer (score 2):

Most of the `Math` functions take `decimal` as well, which has 28 digits of precision.  `Math.Pow` does not, but if `i` is an integer then you should be fine by changing `ret` and `retMin` to `decimal`:

```
// assumptions
decimal retMin = ...
decimal ret = ...
int i = ...

retMin = ((Math.Abs(ret)+Math.Abs(retMin))*(decimal)Math.Pow(-1,Math.Abs(i)));
```

or changing the last component as @Dmitry suggests to avoid a cast (and possible loss of precision):

```
retMin = (Math.Abs(ret)+Math.Abs(retMin))* (i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: maybe include what Dmitry wrote. A Math.Pow on -1 can be replaced with a modulo. and the other operation support long